# Is the data strongly consistent among the Hazelcast nodes in different Kubernetes clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast, key-value-store

Background:
There is a need in our project to store the balance info in a KV store. The KV store need strongly data consistence across DCs(different Kubernetes clusters), because we target to deploy the KV store across 3 DCs(different Kubernetes clusters) for high availability.

Our design:
Deploy HazelCast 3 nodes to 3 different Kubernetes clusters/dockers in 3 different DCs.
It means each DC has 1 Kubernetes cluster, the Hazelcast node is deployed to the docker of the cluster. So total 3 HazelCast nodes to form a cluster.

Our questions:

1. Are those 3 HazelCast nodes able to form a cluster? As we know, they communicate through TCP only. But communicate across different Kubernetes/namespace need to go through Ingress which is HTTP.
2. Is HazelCast able to persist data to the Kubernetes PVC(PersistentVolumeClaim)?
3. Is the data strongly consistent among the 3 Hazelcast nodes? Is it base on Raft?

Comment: Stackoverflow advises asking one question in one post. Please consider creating new posts for each. You may link them by adding references.

Answer (score 1):

1. You probably don't want to form a Hazelcast cluster across different Kubernetes cluster, as network-wise, it wouldn't be very performant. You need to check [WAN Replication](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/wan/wan.html)
2. Hazelcast stores data in-memory and not on disk.
3. [Hazelcast CP subsystem](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/cp-subsystem/cp-subsystem.html) implements Raft. Not all data structures are supported by the CP subsystem, but since you mention KV store - `IMap` is.